# HORM with a writable partition

Tags: write-protect, windows-embedded-7, windows-embedded-8, uwf

To achieve faster boot/shutdown times, as well as securing the data of the operating system, I wish to utilize UWF with HORM (Hibernate Once, Resume Many).

However, a requirement for HORM is that all "fixed volumes" are to be write protected.

I want to have a partition (D:) writable, so that I can log data to it. Is this at all possible?

I tried having only 1 partition on the computer (C:), with a large unpartitioned and unformatted area on the drive. This worked fine. However, as soon as I formatted the remaining disk space, I was no longer able to activate HORM.

What I thought might be possible, was to only have C: mounted when activating HORM, and mount the remaining space as D: when the computer wakes from hibernation.

Is there a way to accomplish this at all?

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, in order for D: to be writeable, it must be unmounted prior to generating the hibernate file.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff794291(v=winembedded.60).aspx